# Does one have to pay a non-Jew back double?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, gezel-stealing

If someone stole from a non-Jew are they required to pay back double like to a Jew?

Comment: Actually, fines are not levied today, so the double pay-back to a Jew is only theoretical until real ordination is restored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rambam rules that although it is completely Biblically prohibited to steal from a gentile (Geneva 1:1), one would only have to pay back the value he stole if he did so (2:1). There is no fine imposed in this case.